# Not every 3-manifold is a graph manifold

Tags: differential-topology, knot-theory, low-dimensional-topology, kirby-diagram

*Surgery presentations*

It is well known that any orientable closed 3-manifold $M$ has a surgery presentation, i.e. can be obtained by doing surgery on $\mathbb{S}^3$ on a link $L$. 
We can also construct a surgery diagram  where the link has all *unknotted* components and two components are either unlinked or an Hopf link. Also we can require that if an unknot component $U_i$ is unlinked from $U_j$ for any $j\neq i$ then $U_i$ is unlinked from $\{U_j\}_{j\neq i}$.
Therefore we can construct a *surgery graph* for  $M$, where each unknot is a vertex and we have an edge between two vertices if they are linked.

*Graph manifolds*

These 3-manifolds are obtained by plumbing on a labelled graph. 
Given a graph we construct a $\mathbb{D}^2$ bundle over $\mathbb{S}^2$ for each vertex (with Euler class given by the label) and then we plumb* two of them whenever the two vertices are connected by an edge. In this way we get a 4-manifold with boundary $X$, the resulting graph manifold is the boundary $\partial X$.

*Confusion*

The $\mathbb{D}^2$ bundle over $\mathbb{S}^2$ of Euler characteristic $n$ has a surgery presentation given by the unknot labelled with $n$. Plumbing corresponds to link two unknots like the Hopf link, at least if we are plumbing on a graph which is a tree. Otherwise when we plumb on an edge that creates a cycle in the graph, then we have to link the two unknots like an Hopf like as before but also add another unknot like in this picture. 
(Before)
[image: Before]

(After the move)
[image: After]

Now  we can use Kirby moves to obtain from this a surgery graph with the properties mentioned above.

> It seems to me that every 3-manifold that has a tree as surgery graph must be a graph manifold. In general, if the graph is not a tree maybe we will get a graph manifold, maybe not. How can we spot from the surgery graph of $M$ if it is a graph manifold? Does these kind of graphs have some particular feature?

*plumbing means identify two trivialized open set of the form $\mathbb{D}^2\times \mathbb{D}^2$by exchanging fiber with base.

Comment: I guess you can always do blowing up to change crossings and by that hopefully you can convert the picture into a graph manifold. The interesting question could be when a graph manifold is a tree?

Comment: @AnubhavMukherjee thank you for your comment. But maybe there is a misunderstanding. It seems to me that you are restating what I have written after the second picture. 
My question concerns  how to distinguish the surgery graph of a generic 3-manifold from the surgery graph of a graph manifold. I expect there might be some feature of the graph that reveals if it is a graph maniifold or not. 

The "confusing" (to me) part I wrote to motivate the problem tries to explain that apparently is not is not simple to draw a surgery graph that yields a non-graph manifold (graph manifolds are a lot).